# Calculating maximum deflection of an alpha particle from an electron

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, conservation-laws, atomic-physics, scattering

Assuming an alpha particle at initial velocity $v$ has about 7400 times the mass of an electron, I want to calculate the maximum deflection angle induced by the electron it elastically collides with. We can assume that the electron is initially at rest.
Apart from momentum and energy conservation what else can I use?

Comment: Momentum and energy conservation should be all you need I think.

Comment: Take into account that you are not given numerically the value of the initial velocity, so you end up having 5 unknowns (deflection angles of electron and alpha particle, velocities of each particle and initial velocity) for only 3 equations (momentum conservation in each direction plus energy conservation). I definitely think you need extra information

Comment: Sorry I see what you are asking.

Comment: You many need to treat the electron relativistically, keep that in mind.

Comment: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/info/solutions/maximum_angle_deflection_sol_3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> Apart from momentum and energy conservation what else can I use?

The mass that you're given is not the rest mass of the alpha particle, which is 7294 times the mass of an electron. You need to extrapolate the velocity from the increased mass.